# transformer for Maven shade plugin to deal with java reflection

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

Maven shade plugin ignores class/package names in Strings, which is typical for Java reflection.
If the library you're trying to "shade" uses Class.forName("originalpackagename...."), the shaded dependency won't work because the original package name will be left unchanged.
same story with code like

```
servlet.addServletWithMapping("org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet",
    URIUtil.SLASH);
```

and to make things worse:

```
private String[] _serverClasses = {
    "-org.mortbay.jetty.plus.annotation.",       // don't hide
    "-org.mortbay.jetty.plus.jaas.",             // don't hide 
    "-org.mortbay.jetty.plus.naming.",           // don't hide
    "-org.mortbay.jetty.plus.jaas.",             // don't hide
    "-org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet", // don't hide
    "org.mortbay.jetty.", 
    "org.slf4j."
};
```

(examples copied from Jetty server source code)

maybe there is some ResourceTransformer already available for Maven Shade, which replaces the original package/class names in the strings source code?..

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this is new behavior since when you asked your question (I'm using version 2.3), but the shade plugin appears to automatically handle package name literals in the Java source files.

However, for resource files, it does not. For example, if you try to shade the log4j packages, and then reference a logger implementation class from log4j.properties, you will have an exception at runtime. I don't see anything specifically for the shade plugin, but I fixed this issue using the third-party maven-replacer-plugin. For example:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin</groupId>
  <artifactId>replacer</artifactId>
  <version>1.5.3</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>prepare-package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>replace</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
  <configuration>
    <basedir>${project.build.directory}</basedir>
    <includes>
      <include>classes/*.properties</include>
    </includes>
    <replacements>
      <replacement>
        <token>org.</token>
        <value>my-shaded-package-root.org.</value>
      </replacement>
    </replacements>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```